# Is it possible to use nbconvert to export a Bokeh plot to a single html file?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, bokeh

I tried to use nbconvert > HTML and [image]it returns random bokeh logos

**here is my code:**

```
import pandas as pd  
from bokeh.plotting import *  
output_notebook()  

df = pd.DataFrame({'rev':[234,345,657,7]})  
df  

line(df['rev'],df['rev'], color="red", line_width=2,  
     title="Archimean", legend="Archimedean")  
show()
```

Answer (score 2):

A small CSS bug made it into 0.5.0 that affects nbconvert output. There is alread a fix checked into master. We will be releasing 0.5.1 early next week.